# How make border between two UIViews look easier on the eyes (programmatically)?

Tags: ipad, uiview, ios6, border, quartz-core

I'm interested in **how iOS developers can programmatically make edges/boundaries/borders between two UIViews look better.** When I drop views onto story boards, the resulting connections between them are really sharp. For example, consider the screenshot below:

[image: My app]

The line between the gray header and the gradient below is really sharp, and **I'm thinking of ways to make the transition between two views easier on the eyes.** It took me a lot of work and experimentation to add the rounded corner shadow around the panel on the left side, but the buttons still do not blend perfectly.

Here's a screenshot of the iOS6 App store. I added red dots around places where additional effects are applied at the boundary between two views:

[image: app store]

- The boundary around the details button has some sort of inner shadow
- The horizontal line between the top and bottom panels seems to have some sort of shadow effect
- There's a very thin border/shadow around the screenshot

  **How can I achieve such look and feel programmatically?** I tried experimenting with shadowPaths and border attributes of CALayer, but it's a lot of work and has to be done very iteratively. **Is there some open source UIView subclass** which looks at it's superview and decides which effects to apply around itself to **more naturally blend** in with the superview?

Here's another example: Adobe Ideas for iPad. I really like how their buttons and panels have subtle borders around them which make transitions appear really good on iPad with retina display.

[image]

Comment: How to make it "look better" is probably not a good question. Please be as specific as you can. Are you asking how to draw shadows? or borders? or choosing nice colors? (the last one is not a very bad fit for StackOverflow)

Comment: Have you considered using a gradient???

Comment: I'm asking for the names of transitions that might've been applied at the red circle areas and how to apply them programmatically. I cannot be specific if I don't really know what takes place at those boundaries.

Answer (score 0):

All of those skills are known as Quartz 2D, apple has a free manual online. Views and Animations are 2 more you will want to read. I have, expect a solid 6 hours of reading, at minimum. You won't spend time on tutorials afterwards, saves time.

Answer (score 0):

I found one way to make images blend more naturally - **assign a semi-transparent border around the view**. For blending into a white background, add more white to color below, for blending into dark, add less white. The result is that the 1 pixel wide semi-transparent border makes the boundary between two sharply contrasting colors less intense.

The advantage of this method is that you are no longer coding in a specific color border. The transparency of the border converts your view's border pixels into a lighter/darker shades of color.

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

view.layer.borderColor =[UIColor colorWithWhite:0.7 alpha:0.7].CGColor;
view.layer.borderWidth = 1;
```